# ibm iSeries AS400 macro page down until last page

Tags: macros, ibm-midrange

Trying to create a macro for when I perform End of Day in which I have to terminate all active sessions on the IBM AS400 iSeries.  Part of this process is to put a 1 next to all users and then page down, then repeat.

Currently I have a macro when I'm at the WMS Shutdown screen to just put a 1 next to all users on that page and automatically page down.  I'd have to keep pressing that button until I get to the last page, in which I will error out and then have to process the shutdown command to terminate all active users.

I've been working on trying to hone this so that I just have to press it once and it'll automatically remove all users.  the page-by-page macro looks like this:

```
sub subSub1_()
     autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

     autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
     autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
     autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
     autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "111111111111"
     autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
     autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"
end sub
```

When I get to the last page, this will error out in which I have to press the tab button to clear the error message and then continue on.  Is there a way to do a Do While/Until loop until I either can't page down anymore or the WaitForInputReady times out after there's no more InputReady?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you terminate all interactive users without doing anything else.

And assuming that your users are running in the default QINTER subsystem and your console runs in the default QCTL subsystem...

Then from the console, a simple `ENDSBS SBS(QINTER) OPTION(*IMMED)` will terminate all the user jobs.

Comment: I gotta close the comm lines and then shut down WMS in order to perform End of Day.  But I could try to incorporate that ENDSBS command before I do the other stuff I need to do during my WMS shutdown process

Comment: @Zach85 rather than try to do all of that via client access macro, you should use system APIs and CL/RPG programs to do it.  You'd and your company be much better off to have your own SHUTDOWN command.